# Why is uint8_t * const Tx_Buf used in this function prototype?

Tags: c, arrays, string

Below is the prototype declaration of a function:

```
MD_STATUS R_UART0_Send(uint8_t *const tx_buf, uint16_t tx_num);
```

The above function is used for data transmission via a UART.
I have pass parameter to this function but this gives me error, i.e parameter list error.

```
MD_STATUS R_UART0_Send("TEPL", 5);
```

Can you help me understand why this `uint8_t const` is used?

```
/* Function Name: R_UART0_Send
 * Description  : This function sends UART0 data.
 * Arguments    : tx_buf - transfer buffer pointer
 *                tx_num -buffer size
 * Return Value : status - MD_OK or MD_ARGERROR
*/
MD_STATUS R_UART0_Send(uint8_t * const tx_buf, uint16_t tx_num)
{
    MD_STATUS status = MD_OK;

    if (tx_num < 1U)
    {
        status = MD_ARGERROR;
    }
    else
    {
        gp_uart0_tx_address = tx_buf;
        g_uart0_tx_count = tx_num;
        STMK0 = 1U;    /* disable INTST0 interrupt */
        TXD0 = *gp_uart0_tx_address;
        gp_uart0_tx_address++;
        g_uart0_tx_count--;
        STMK0 = 0U;    /* enable INTST0 interrupt */
    }

    return (status);
}
```

Above is the definition of my function

Comment: Are you really putting the return type in your call to the function?

Comment: *"...but this gives me error i.e Parameter list error."* [Edit] your question and add **complete** error message as text (not as image).

Comment: 1) If this function reads from `tx_buf` and sends to UART, its parameter's signature should be `const uint8_t * tx_buf` to indicate that the buffer won't change. Making the pointer const (the way it is now) accomplishes absolutely nothing. 2) you need to store the result in a variable, i.e. `MD_STATUS result = R_UART0_Send("TEPL", 5);`. 3) Enable warnings and note that `"TEPL"` is a string literal (array of `char`), not an array of `uint8_t`.

Comment: Btw, [this PDF](https://www.renesas.com/en-us/doc/products/mpumcu/apn/rl78/002/r01an3278ej0100_rl78.pdf) which is the *single* hit Google gave me, doesn't have `const` in the argument. But perhaps it's old and Renesas is trying to improve. I think it's a really bad usage of `const`, and I'm like Captain `const`.

Comment: If you don't like the signature, what types would you prefer and why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Parameter type `uint8_t *const tx_buf` means ***Constant pointer to non-constant data***.

Which means that pointer variable cannot be changed where it points to, however, data can be changed by this pointer where it points to in this function. But this is not a problem so far.

Problem is your function call. You are calling your function with constant data (string literal) and they cannot be modified.

Now you have 2 options (pick one, I would first one):

**Modify function parameters to more useful type**

```
MD_STATUS R_UART0_Send(const uint8_t *tx_buf, uint16_t tx_num);
R_UART0_Send("TEPL", 5);
```

**Do not call function with string literal**

```
char data[] = "TEPL"; //Make array first with your string
R_UART0_Send(data, 5); //Pass it to original function
```

Comment: I stand corrected, the *constant pointer to non-constant* threw me.

Comment: It's OK to call the function with string literal. The function doesn't modify the input

Comment: @M.M It is hard to say *it is OK* because if I tomorrow start modifying it, I will have undefined behavior, in most cases *segmentation fault*.

Comment: @M.M That's you way to say *oops, I failed this time*? ;)

Comment: The only failure here is the pointless advice to not use a string literal

Comment: @M.M I can see your arrogance here when you fail. And thanks for downvote, what is funny is that OP solved a problem with my proposals.

Answer (score -1):

Probably because the function was written to handle Unicode in the most modern approach permitted within C.

By using the  guaranteed fixed-width integers, you can transmit guaranteed 8-bit bytes, and have UTF-8 string not be mangled by all sorts of assumptions about how long a character is.

Comment: It seems reasonable for a function transmitting data to a serial port to send bytes instead of chars, I don't think the underlying reasoning had anything to do with encoding.

Comment: @Groo It seams reasonable, until those bytes don't map up to sensible chars.   UTF-8 characters are composed, for all codepoints above the 128th codepont.  The two to four uint8_t compositions can contain 8 bit values that are interpreted radically differently when being interpreted as legacy chars.  The use of a different type is a flag that brings more attention to think of these are numbers, and not as stand-alone characters.

Comment: It's not my downvote, just to make clear, but I was just saying that sending *data* over an UART generally means sending *bytes*, not ASCII or Unicode characters. So I would find it much weirder if the prototype had a `char` pointer (or `LPSTR`, as Microsoft would do).

Comment: @Groo I've been playing Stackoverflow too long to personally attribute a downvote to a comment.  But I agree, the legacy of C is such that byte and char are often used interchangeably, when in both cases the history was such that 8 bits was often assumed, and (like most of C) rarely guaranteed.  uint8_t makes a guarantee, and differentiates between the legacy chars.  That's all I wanted to say, and I hope I said it!  Cheers :)